# Connecting to Github from remote server via shared internet

Tags: git, ssh

I have shared my local internet by an offline remote server using [this documentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh). Everything is working, the remote server has internet now. Most of things like apt, curl, etc is working. But when I want to connect to github via command below:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: `Temporary failure in name resolution` means your system was unable to look up the IP address for `github.com`. If it goes away on its own, there is no problem: the temporary failure was truly temporary. If not, the problem has to do with the name resolution on your system. This is a matter for superuser.com.

Comment: The problem is that I should define a proxy for git to connect to internet via it. The question is: how could I define proxy in git config?

Comment: You don't, at least when using ssh. ssh itself can be told to go through a proxy. Git just *runs* ssh, to get a channel through which it can send data. Everything is up to ssh itself, in terms of making the connection.

Answer (score 2):

If curl is working, but not SSH, try at least to clone with HTTPS:

```
git clone https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>
```

You might then have to define a proxy (`HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY`), if needed, with a `NO_PROXY` set to "127.0.0.1,localhost,.mycompany.com".

Still using ssh would mean, as suggested by the OP:

- `git config https.proxy http://a/proxy`
- using [`bryanpkc/corkscrew`](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew), a tool for tunneling SSH through HTTP proxies

(Assuming this does not go against local IT policy)

See for instance "[Using Corkscrew to tunnel SSH over HTTP](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/using-corkscrew-to-tunnel-ssh-over-http/)" from [Vincent Danen](https://twitter.com/vdanen):

> edit your SSH configuration file, ~/.ssh/config, and add:
>
> ```yaml
> Host somehost
>    Hostname somehost.example.com #ssh.github.com for Github
>    Port 443 #443 for Github
>    ProxyCommand /user/bin/corkscrew proxy.example.com 3129 %h %p
> ```
>
> OpenSSH transparently converts the `%h` to the hostname to connect to (`somehost.example.com`) and the port to connect to (22, by default).
>
> The `ProxyCommand` line here is telling OpenSSH to start the Corkscrew program to make the actual connection to the end SSH server. >
> You can create multiple entries for all of the hosts you may need to connect to, or use a simple regular expression or the global asterisk (`*`) in the `Host` line (`*` will tell OpenSSH to use this `Host` stanza for all connections).

Comment: The HTTPS is working normally. What I need is exactly SSH! I tried to use Corkscrew and it seems the problem is solved via defining a proxy inside git config.

Comment: @weera so Corkscrew works with `git config https.proxy`?

Comment: @weera OK. I have edited the answer accordingly, to add an example.